# how to close multi thread tcp listener

Tags: vb.net, multithreading, tcp

I worked on this listener ( I did not try to connect any clients to it until now).
I have this problem.

When starting the listener it started OK without any problem. so I added a stop listener button to this application and I tried to do listener.stop() but it throws an exception:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s4zxk.png)

A first chance exception of type 'System.ObjectDisposedException' occurred in System.dll

Until now I did not try to connect any client after the listener started, I only used start listener and stop listener buttons and the listener throws an exception.

How I gracefully shut down this listener without the exception ?

```
Imports System.IO, System.Net, System.Net.Sockets

Public Class frmServer
    Dim Listener As TcpListener
    Dim Client As TcpClient
    Dim ClientList As New List(Of ChatClient)
    Dim sReader As StreamReader
    Dim cClient As ChatClient

    Sub xLoad() Handles Me.Load
        Listener = New TcpListener(IPAddress.Any, 3818)
        Listener.Start()
        xUpdate("Server Started", False)
        Listener.BeginAcceptTcpClient(New AsyncCallback(AddressOf AcceptClient), Listener)
    End Sub

    Sub AcceptClient(ByVal ar As IAsyncResult)
        cClient = New ChatClient(Listener.EndAcceptTcpClient(ar))
        AddHandler (cClient.MessageRecieved), AddressOf MessageRecieved
        AddHandler (cClient.ClientExited), AddressOf ClientExited
        ClientList.Add(cClient)
        xUpdate("New Client Joined", True)
        Listener.BeginAcceptTcpClient(New AsyncCallback(AddressOf AcceptClient), Listener)
    End Sub

    Sub MessageRecieved(ByVal Str As String)
        xUpdate(Str, True)
    End Sub

    Sub ClientExited(ByVal Client As ChatClient)
        ClientList.Remove(Client)
        xUpdate("Client Exited", True)
    End Sub

    Delegate Sub _xUpdate(ByVal Str As String, ByVal Relay As Boolean)
    Sub xUpdate(ByVal Str As String, ByVal Relay As Boolean)
        On Error Resume Next
        If InvokeRequired Then
            Invoke(New _xUpdate(AddressOf xUpdate), Str, Relay)
        Else
            txtMainTextBox.AppendText(Str & vbNewLine)
            If Relay Then Send(Str)
        End If
    End Sub

    Private Sub TextBox2_KeyDown(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.KeyEventArgs) Handles txtSendTextBox.KeyDown

    End Sub

    Sub Send(ByVal Str As String)
        For i As Integer = 0 To ClientList.Count - 1
            Try
                ClientList(i).Send(Str)
            Catch
                ClientList.RemoveAt(i)
            End Try
        Next
    End Sub

    Private Sub btnSend_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnSend.Click
        If Me.txtSendTextBox.Text = "" Then
            Exit Sub
        End If

        xUpdate("Server Says: " & Me.txtSendTextBox.Text, True)
        txtSendTextBox.Clear()

    End Sub

    Private Sub btnStopListener_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnStopListener.Click
        Listener.Stop()
       'this part stopped the listener but it throws an exception

    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: Show us the stack trace of the exception, which you should have already looke3d at yourself. The fact that you may not be able to understand some information doesn't mean that you shouldn't look at it and it certainly doesn't mean that you shouldn't pass it on to us.

Comment: I have updated the thread by attaching the screen shot of the exception.

Comment: That's just a first-chance exception. That's not a problem. That just means that an exception has been thrown. Code is allowed to throw exceptions. It's when exceptions are thrown but not caught that there's an issue.

Comment: Thank you , I have been struggling for the last week to solve this exception, really thank you.

Comment: @user18387401: Be a bit patient with Andrew, he is new here. Welcome! An ObjectDisposedException you get - as the name suggests - when you attempt to access an object that is disposed, e.g. a connection that was closed etc.